# Как можно получить системный диск и разделитель?

Tags: node.js, файлы

Мне нужно проверить наличие папки на компьютере, и если такой папки нет — создать ее, скачать в нее файлы и установить программу. Можно ли как-то получить Системный раздел диска c операционной системой?

То есть в модуле Path есть

```
path.delimiter
```

Который возвращает системный разделитель `\` или `/` в зависимости от операционной системы. Есть ли что-то типа `path.systemdisk`?

Comment: Что-то готовое [GitHub drivelist](https://github.com/balena-io-modules/drivelist)

Comment: Это только под Виндовс? Постольку в Линуксе там нет буквы.

Comment: Можно прочитать какую-нибудь переменную окружения, например, WINDOWS  и получить первый символ

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В большинстве случаев для Windows вам может подойти:

```
> process.env.SystemDrive
'C:'
```

Посмотрите ещё список переменных окружения в `process.env`, может, получится выбрать то, что покажется вам наиболее надёжным.